# th:field causes org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor (500 error)

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to do validation for the `input` fields on thymeleaf, and everything was working fine until i added in `th:field` for the validation

> Causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor
>   plain target object for bean name 'person1' available as request
>   attribute

also, i don't know what causes it
My entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @NotNull(message = "cannot be null")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

My Controller :

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/All", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllPerson(Model model) {
        ArrayList<Person> listPerson = personService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("listPerson",listPerson);
        return "/All";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editPerson(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="person1") PersonRequest person, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/All";
        }
        else {
            personService.update(person.getId(), person.getName());
            return "redirect:All";
        }
    }
}
```

My Form :

```
<div id ="EditModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <form class="modal-dialog" th:action="@{/Edit}" th:object="${person1}" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" id="edit-modal-person-id" name="id" value=""/>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" id="edit-modal-person-name" name="name" value=""/>
                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" class="label label-danger" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</p>
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="PhoneNumberEdit">Edit Phone Number</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" id="SubmitEdit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".buttonEdit").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url : "/GetOnePerson",
                        data : 'id=' + id,
                        datatype : "text",
                        success : function(result){
                            $('#edit-modal-person-id').val(result.id);
                            $('#edit-modal-person-name').val(result.name);
                            $('#PhoneNumberEdit').prop('th:attr','data-id='+id);
                        },
                        error : function(){
                            alert("ERROR");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Is there anyway to avoid using th:field? or any alternative way to validate field?

Comment: Remove the attribute value from your inputs and keep only th:field

Comment: still doesn't work, even if i added in th:value or remove the value attribute altogether it's still returning the same error

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Struggling with it myself